# Docker, python3 yaml.safe_load() read chinese file can't work

Tags: python, docker

recently I am writing a static page generator.
I want to use docker to deploy my project. I use python3.

```
def load_posts_config(config):
    metadata = {}
    for c in os.listdir(config['articles']['config']):
        cpath = os.path.join(config['articles']['config'], c)
        cfh = open(cpath, 'r')
        meta = yaml.safe_load(cfh)
        cfh.close()
        metadata[meta['post_id']] = meta
    return metadata
```

In the config file of `cfh`, there are some Chinese characters. I run my script well **in my own Ubuntu 16.04LTS, python3.5.2**. However, when I ran it in the docker (where python version is 3.5.3), it output error:

```
root@a0affea32648:/build/blog# python3 bumblebee.py           
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bumblebee.py", line 80, in <module>
    article_infos = load_posts_config(config)
  File "bumblebee.py", line 56, in load_posts_config
    meta = yaml.safe_load(cfh)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 70, in load
    loader = Loader(stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/loader.py", line 34, in __init__
    Reader.__init__(self, stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 85, in __init__
self.determine_encoding()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 124, in determine_encoding
self.update_raw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 178, in update_raw
data = self.stream.read(size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It's quite strange. I think python3 can handle all unicode and I can run it well on my local computer. **The only differences are the python version and environment, python3.5.2 in Ubuntu16.04lts works and python3.5.3 in docker doesn't.**

Is there any one who knows the problem?
Or how to update python3.5.2 to python3.5.3 in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?
Or somewhere properer to ask for help?

Thx in advance.

(PS: I have tried `yaml.load()` but failed)

Comment: Try this and see if it works `import io; cfh = io.open(cpath, 'r', encoding="utf-8");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have found the cause.

The diffence between the two environments is the default character encoding, you can use this script to check the default encoding:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
```

In my Ubuntu16.4lts it is 'UTF-8', while in the docker server it is 'ANSI_X3.4-1968'. So we need to specify an encoding parameter when we open a file. Then it can work.

In addition, in the docker server, we can't use chinese charcters as file name because in the docker server the default character encoding doesn't support chinese character. So the Chinese filename in the docker will become sth like '2017-08-19-????????????.yml'. If you make sure all your file name is ascii character and specify an encoding parameter when we open a file in python3. Then everything is ok.

More details are [here](http://www.diveintopython3.net/files.html).

Solution:
In Dockerfile, add these code:

```
ENV LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && \
    cp /etc/locale.alias /usr/share/locale/ && \
    locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && \
    /usr/sbin/update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

It works in nginx:latest images. It's may depend on the docker images cause only specifying ENV LANG C.UTF-8 can't fix in my docker image.

Answer (score 1):

you can specify `ENV LANG C.UTF-8` in your docker file to workaround this issue (important in cases where the open command is in a 3rd party library you don't want to change)

Comment: thx. I have tried this but failed. Maybe it depends on the docker images. I have updated my post adding my solution.